# Grails/Groovy - Returning MySQL records in Map only keep last record

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy

I am attempting to iterate through a table data and save the table records into a Groovy Map, but only the last record is saved in the map.

**Service Code**

```
class EmployeeService {

    def dataSource

    def printTable(){
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        def tableMap = [:]
        int count=0
        sql.eachRow("SELECT * FROM employee") { row ->
            tableMap.'first_name' = row.first_name
            tableMap.'last_name' = row.last_name
            tableMap.'born' = row.born
            print "\nIteration No " + count
            count++
        }
        sql.close()
        for ( e in tableMap ) {print "key = ${e.key}, value = ${e.value}"}
    }
```

Table Records of Employee below:

[image]

This is what the Map has after finishing the iterations:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    def list = []
    int count = 0
    sql.eachRow("SELECT * FROM employee") { row ->
        def tableMap = [:]
        tableMap.'first_name' = row.first_name
        tableMap.'last_name' = row.last_name
        tableMap.'born' = row.born
        list << tableMap
        print "\nIteration No " + count
        count++
    }
    list.each {
    for (def e in it) {
        print "key = ${e.key}, value = ${e.value}"
    }
}
```

You need to create a list to store all the maps, otherwise the old value in the map will be replaced by new value.

Comment: Or just use sql.rows() which returns a GroovyResultSet.  No need to loop over each result like that.